# How to extract editable PDF data from an iframe and send it to a server API in React? Open to suggestions or external packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, fetch, pdf.js

I am working on a React project where I have loaded an existing editable PDF from a URL and created its buffer. I have then passed this array buffer of the editable PDF document to an iframe, where the fields are editable, and I have verified this.

Now, I want to implement the functionality to get the PDF data back from the iframe and send it back to the server using another endpoint. However, I am having trouble achieving this.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";

const LoadPDF = () => {
  const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState("");
  const viewer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    modifyPdf();
  }, []);

  const modifyPdf = async () => {
    const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(
      "<path_to_pdf>"
    ).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());

    const bytes = new Uint8Array(existingPdfBytes);
    const blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/pdf" });
    const docUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setPdfUrl(docUrl);
  };
`your text`
  const savePdf = async () => {
    const iframe = viewer.current;
    const iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

    const pdfDocument = await iframeWindow.PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument
      .getDocument()
      .promise;
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDocument.save();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", new Blob([pdfBytes]), "test.pdf");

    const response = await fetch("<path_to_save_pdf>", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={savePdf}>Save PDF</button>
      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
        <iframe
          width="1500"
          height={window.innerHeight - 50}
          title="test-frame"
          ref={viewer}
          src={pdfUrl}
          type="application/pdf"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoadPDF;
```

When I click the "Save PDF" button, I am not able to reach the logs until the fetch call in savePdf.

Can you guys suggest a solution to this issue? Additionally, I believe we can fetch the buffer array from the iframe without using any external APIs, correct me if am wrong

NOTE: the pdf i am loading contains AcroForm fields, I just want to add data to those fieds and save the response back to server(maybe replace the original pdf with the edited pdf)

I have tried a few different approaches to get the PDF data back from the iframe and send it to the server. Initially, I tried using the pdf-lib package to modify the PDF programmatically, but that didn't work as it was not my requirement. Then, I tried using the pdf.js package to get the PDF data from the iframe, but I was not able to reach the logs till the fetch call in savePdf function, and I was not able to figure out why.

I also tried using a different approach by using the File API to get the PDF data from the iframe, but that did not work either. Finally, I tried using the iframeWindow.PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.save() function to get the PDF data, but I was not able to get it to work.

My expected outcome was to be able to get the PDF data back from the iframe and send it to the server to store the PDF. However, I have not been successful so far. I would appreciate any help or guidance on this matter.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the suggestion, however my company wants me to save the edited pdf back to server, this use case can not modified, also if there is any other way to achieve the same(without iframe) so I am open to those as well. Thanks